# Как задать права на запуска фаила, упакованного pyinstaller-ом

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Мне нужно сделать так чтобы, после упаковки файла с помощью pyinstaller при двойном клике он запускался от имени администратора. Пробовал через файл манифеста, не получилось.

Comment: Подойдет? https://codeby.net/threads/zapuskaem-skript-python-ot-imeni-administratora-v-windows.79779/

Answer (score 0):

Правой кнопкой клик по exe файлу, свойства, вкладка совместимость, галка запускать от имени администратора.

> пробывал, у меня работает но вот когда отправляю кому то у него нет

Тогда в программе проверять пользователя

```
import ctypes

def is_admin():
    return ctypes.windll.shell32.IsUserAnAdmin() != 0

if is_admin():
    print("Программа запущена от имени администратора.")
else:
    print("Программа запущена не от имени администратора.")
```

Comment: пробывал, у меня работает но вот когда отправляю кому то у него нет

Comment: @smit1x обновил ответ